# How to update Visual Studio Team Foundataion Server Window Postitions

Tags: multiple-monitors, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, team-foundation-server

I use two monitors with with TFS 2008 backward compatibility plugin and in VS TFS 2010. I had to move desks and ended up changing the location of my second monitor form the right side to the left. I have noticed that when I try to resolve conflicts or view change set details that VS 2008 and 2010 seemed to lock up. What was happening was that the window was popping up for those actions in the location for the old monitor arrangement and was not visible.

Know I know, and have already had to use, the method of right clicking on the task bar for a off screen window and selecting move. Then using mouse or keyboard to more the window back into view. The thing is that with TFS these windows do not show up on the task bar or in task manager. Right now when I think this is the case I am switching the orientation of my monitors and moving the window to the original display. Is there ANY other way to do think because my work around is very clunky.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try resetting the window layout in Visual Studio.

On the **Window** menu, click **Reset Window Layout** and see if that resolves it.